# Can I reduce while mapping?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to convert command line arguments and sum of them.

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final int[] array = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(arg -> {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(arg);
            } catch (final NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.err.println("wrong arg: " + arg);
            }
        }).toArray();
    final int total = IntStream.of(array).sum();
}
```

Can I actually reduce(`total`) while mapping it?

I need both `array` and `total`, anyway.

Comment: Your code does not compile. You can’t catch exceptions in a function without returning a value. Besides that, there is no point in trying to do that in one step at all costs. The result will be more complicated than just getting your array and performing a trivial summing operation over the array and whether there will be a performance difference and in which direction is hard to predict.

Answer (score 2):

Why not this:

```
final int total = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(arg -> {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(arg);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("wrong arg: " + arg);
        }
    }).sum();
```

Sources:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html

Comment: I need both the `array` and the `total`, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways:
Use stream to sum at the beginning:

```
 int sum =Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(arg -> {
            try {
                return Integer.parseInt(arg);
            } catch (final NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.err.println("wrong arg: " + arg);
                return 0;
            }
        }).sum();
        System.out.print(sum);
```

Or sum during processing:

```
    int sum[] =new int[1];

    Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(arg -> {
        try {
             return Integer.parseInt(arg);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("wrong arg: " + arg);
            return 0;
        }
    })
            .peek(value-> sum[0]+=value)
            .toArray();
    System.out.print(sum[0]);
```

But the second option is not looking nice, I would discourage you to do so.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 I believe that's because we need to change the value from inside the lambda expression.

Comment: You cannot pass a mutable property inside a lmbda, its final, so there is a small trick from old times, that allows to modify a variable outside of lambda.

Comment: But  as I said, this is highly unwanted.

Comment: @Beri Will it be too excessive? [LongAdder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html)?

Comment: It's against clean code principals. Lambda expression should not modify anything outside it's body, when you are using streams, It could lead to errors, secondly this stream is single-thread, but if the stream would be running in parallel, your value could be unpredictable, due to lack of sync..

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `Pair` or `Tuple`, sadly **Java** doesn't support this, maybe you can try [appache common Pair](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/ImmutablePair.html), There is an example use `reduce` with `Pair`:

```
    ImmutablePair<Integer, List<Integer>> res = Arrays.stream(strings).map(arg -> {
        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(arg);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println("wrong arg: " + arg);
            throw nfe;
        }
    }).reduce(ImmutablePair.of(0, new ArrayList<Integer>()), (pair, integer) ->
    {
        pair.getRight().add(integer);
        return ImmutablePair.of(pair.getLeft() + integer, pair.getRight());
    }, (pair1, pair2) -> {
        pair1.getRight().addAll(pair2.getRight());
        return ImmutablePair.of(pair1.getLeft() + pair2.getLeft(), pair1.getRight());
    });
```